# How to get updated DOM/document in Greasemonkey [Firefox]?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, greasemonkey

I'm trying to print the document, however it returns the old document and not the new one.  Does anyone know how  I can get the updated document once the child node has been added?

````
    const targetNode = document.getElementById('randomNode');
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    const callback = async function(mutationList, observer) {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
              await delay(2000);
              console.log(document) // <==This line
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        }
    }
};```
````

Comment: Don't `await` in the observer callback loop — that blocks it: `delay(2000).then(() => console.log(document))`

Comment: `document` will always be the same because it's just an interface.